# What are bad operand types for binary operator '||'?

Tags: java, operands

The error I got is-

```
Main.java:23: error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'
                if(c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c='o'||c=='u'||c=='y')
                                         ^
  first type:  boolean
  second type: char
```

I didnt really quite understand it.

Comment: They are short circuit operators.

Comment: c='o' is not a comparison, it is an assignment.

Comment: `c='o'` is the problem

Comment: You should really refactor this into `setOfValidChoices.contains(c)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this:

```
c='o'
```

in your `if` condition.

Probably you are just doing this assignment by mistake. So you may want to update this to comparison using

```
c=='o'
```

Comment: This is the reason, why one should keep boolean expressions simple and extract such conditions into a method where each comparison is a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
||c='o'||c=='u'
```

you were using an assignment operator.

```
||c=='o'||c=='u'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c='o'||c=='u'||c=='y')
```

change `c='o'` to `c=='o'`

Actually `assignment` was happening in your `if` statement which is not allowed